# Variance 0 in the covariate matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I made a matrix of covariates. It works well.
Question: How do I make the variances between the covariates 0 and the variance of that variable 1, as the image shows?

```
set.seed(1)
M1<-matrix(rnorm(25,5,1),ncol=5)
M1
cor(M1)
SD_M1<-rnorm(5)
M1_Covariance<-(SD_M1%*%t(SD_M1))*cor(M1)
M1_Covariance
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function `f` taking as arguments a covariance matrix `S` and an integer index vector `k`. It sets the variances of the variables indexed by `k` to 1 and the covariances involving those variables to 0.

```r
function(S, k) {
  S[k, ] <- S[, k] <- 0
  S[cbind(k, k)] <- 1
  S
}

f(M1_Covariance, c(1:2, 5L))
```

```
     [,1] [,2]      [,3]       [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0  0.000000  0.0000000    0
[2,]    0    1  0.000000  0.0000000    0
[3,]    0    0  2.163113 -0.4791670    0
[4,]    0    0 -0.479167  0.2286275    0
[5,]    0    0  0.000000  0.0000000    1
```

`S` could really be any square matrix, since the operation doesn't depend on `S` being symmetric or positive definite.

Comment: Thanks, very good solution! One question: if I wanted to have more columns and rows with 0 and 1 as in the previous case, how should I modify the code?

Comment: I've updated the code.